# FireDAC Query RecordCountMode

Tags: firedac

I am trying to configure a FireDAC TFDQuery component so it fetches records on demand in batches of no more than 500, but I need it to report back what is the total record count for the query not just the number of fetched records. The `FetchOptions` are configured as follows:

```
FetchOptions.AssignedValues = [evMode, evRowsetSize, evRecordCountMode, evCursorKind, evAutoFetchAll]
FetchOptions.CursorKind = ckForwardOnly
FetchOptions.AutoFetchAll = afTruncate
FetchOptions.RecordCountMode = cmTotal
FetchOptions.RowSetSize = 500
```

This immediately returns all records in the table not just 500. I have tried setting `RecsMax` to 500, which works in limiting the fetched records, but  `RecordCount` for the query shows only 500 not the total.

The FireDAC help file states that setting `RecordCountMode` to `cmTotal' causes FireDAC to issue

> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (original SQL command text).

Either there is a bug or I am doing something wrong!

I cannot see what other properties I can change. I am confused as to the relationship between `RowSetSize` and `RecsMax` and din't find the help file clarified.

I have tried playing with the properties of `AutoFetchAll` (Again confused as to this properties' purpose), but noting that is was set to `afAll` I set it to `afTruncate` to see if that would make a difference, but it didn't.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Even though assuming that the mode is set to `fmOnDemand`, FireDAC fetches only at most `RowSetSize` number of tuples in this case. The `AutoFetchAll` option can affect fetching of all tuples only in special cases. I assume that you only `Open` the cursor and iterate through the resultset to fetch another batch. Could we have a MCVE with details about DBMS, please? Also, how do you measure how many tuples is fetched in the storage?

Comment: i assume then that RecsMax has nothing to do with it? The database is MySQL 5.6. Mode is indeed `fmOnDemand`. With the query's ` FetchOptions` set as in original post, I run `FDQuery.open` and then iterate as assumed. The call to `Open` returns the correct `RecordCount`, but fetches all tuples ie 25000 odd. I check this by re-running the query with its `RecordCountMode` set to `cmFetched`. If in addition, I set `RecsMax` to 500 then set `RecordCountMode` to `cmFetched` it reports 500 tuples fetched as expected, and  when re-run set to `cmTotal` it reports 500 tuples  not the expected 25000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested `FetchOptions`' `fmOnDemand` `Mode` with a `FDTable` component and a `FDQuery` component. Both with identical settings for `FetchOptions` ie `RowSetSize`=50. 425,000 rows in the dataset fetched over a network server.

`FDTable` performs as expected. It loads just 50 tuples and does so almost instantly. When pressing Ctrl+End to get to the end of the DBGrid display, it loads just 100 tuples. Whilst scrolling it rarely loads more than 100 tuples. Impact on memory negligible. But it is slow in scrolling.

`FDQuery` loads 50 tuples, but takes around 35 seconds to do so and consumes over 0.5GB of memory in the process. If you press Ctrl+Home to move to the end of the connected DBGrid it does so virtually instantly and in the process loads the entire table and consumes a further 700MB of memory.

I also experimented with `CachedUpdates`. The results above where with `CachedUpdates` off. When on, there was no impact at all on the performance of `FDQuery` (still poor), but for `FDTable` it resulted in it loading the entire table at start up, taking over half a minute to do so and consuming 1.2GBs of memory.

It looks like `fmOnDemand` mode is only practically usable with `FDTable` with `CachedUpdates` off and is not suitable for use with `FDQuery` at all.

Comment: The `Mode` is known to work (how many tuples is currently in the internal client storage you can check by the `FDQuery.Table.Rows.Count` property).

Comment: I have posted the details of my research in my amended answer. I just can't get `FDQuery` to work with `fmOnDemand` in any meaningful way.

Comment: I'll dig into this deeper later (sorry, holidays :)

Comment: If trying to use `FDQuery` it seems you also need to set `FDConnection`'s `ResultMode` to `rmUse`. Doing this, loads only the RowSetSize number of tuples and only loads the necessary tuples when paging down. However, if you press Ctrl+End, it loads the whole dataset. I have only tried with MySQL so it may be a MySQL quirk. I am about to test with PostgreSQL and will post the results

Comment: Well, pressing `Ctrl+End` sounds obviously like that you're using some kind of data aware control. That control may affect loading, keep that in mind... And I'd try to help (to reproduce what you claim about, just need more time), just couldn't reproduce what you claim about. If you add a MCVE (including all the table creation and filling stuff), it will be ideal ;-)!

Answer (score 0):

The results of my tests using `fmOnDemand` with postgreSQL and MySQL are basically the same. With FDTable `fmOnDemand` only downloads what it needs limited to the `RowSetSize`. With a `RowSetSize` of 50 it initially downloads 50 tuples and no matter where you scroll to it never downloads more than 111 tuples (though doubtless that is dependent on the size of the connected `DBGrid`. If you disconnect the `FDTable` from a data source it initially downloads 50 tuples and if you then navigate to any record in the underlying table it downloads one tuple only and discards all other data.

`FDQuery` in `fmOnDemand` downloads only the initial 50 tuples when opened, but if you navigate by `RecNo` it downloads every tuple in between. I had rather hoped it would use LIMIT and OFFSET commands to get only records that were being requested.

To recreate the test for PostGre you need the following FireDAC components:

```
object FDConnectionPG: TFDConnection
Params.Strings = (      
  'Password='
  'Server='
  'Port='
  'DriverID=PG')
ResourceOptions.AssignedValues = [rvAutoReconnect]
ResourceOptions.AutoReconnect = True    
end

object FDQueryPG: TFDQuery
Connection = FDConnectionPG
FetchOptions.AssignedValues = [evMode, evRowsetSize]    
end

object FDTable1: TFDTable
CachedUpdates = True
Connection = FDConnectionPG
FetchOptions.AssignedValues = [evMode, evRowsetSize, evRecordCountMode]
FetchOptions.RecordCountMode = cmFetched
end
```

If you wish to recreate it with MYSQL, you will basically need the same FireDAC components, but the `FDConnection`needs to be set as follows:

```
object FDConnectionMySql: TFDConnection
Params.Strings = (
  'DriverID=MySQL'
  'ResultMode=Use')
ResourceOptions.AssignedValues = [rvAutoReconnect]
ResourceOptions.AutoReconnect = True   
end
```

You'll need an edit box, two buttons, a checkbox, a timer and a label and the following code:

```
procedure TfrmMain.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
if not FDQueryPG.IsEmpty then
  begin
    FDQueryPG.EmptyDataSet;
    FDQueryPG.ClearDetails;
    FDQueryPG.Close;
  end;

if not FDTable1.IsEmpty then
  begin
    FDTAble1.EmptyDataSet;
    FDTable1.ClearDetails;
    FDTable1.Close;
  end;


lFetched.Caption := 'Fetched 0';
lFetched.Update;

if cbTable.checked then
  begin
    FDTable1.TableName := '[TABLENAME]';
    FDTable1.Open();
    lFetched.Caption := 'Fetched '+ FDTable1.Table.Rows.Count.ToString;
  end
else
  begin
    FDQueryPG.SQL.Text := 'Select * from [TABLENAME]';        
    FDQueryPG.open;
    lFetched.Caption := 'Fetched '+ FDQueryPG.Table.Rows.Count.ToString;
  end;
timer1.Enabled:=true;    
end;

procedure TfrmMain.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if cbTable.Checked then
   FDTable1.RecNo := strToInt(Edit1.Text)
  else
   FDQueryPG.RecNo := strToInt(Edit1.Text);
end;

procedure TfrmMain.cbTableClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  timer1.Enabled := False;
end;

procedure TfrmMain.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if cbTable.checked then
    lFetched.Caption := 'Fetched '+ FDTable1.Table.Rows.Count.ToString
  else        
    lFetched.Caption:='Fetched '+FDQueryPG.Table.Rows.Count.ToString;
  lFetched.Update;
end;
```